# CakePHP 3 RESTful custom method

Tags: php, json, rest, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

In CakePHP 2, I use a custom controller as version of my API something like `V01Controller`, `V02Controller`, ... with some method inside and response JSON data.

so when user request a method `getUpdate` by calling `/api/v01/getUpdate.json?lastUpdated=1234567890` or `/api/v02/getUpdate.json?lastUpdated=1234567890` it works as expected.

Currently I want to upgrade my CakePHP project to version 3. and I want to keep URL the same as the old CakePHP version 2.

In CakePHP 2, the configuration in `routes.php` is :

```
Router::mapResources(array('V01'));
Router::parseExtensions('json');
```

Here what I try so far but It is not working in CakePHP 3 :

In `routes.php`:

```
Router::scope('/api', function ($routes) {
    $routes->extensions(['json', 'html']);
    $routes->resources('V01');
});
```

In `V01Controller`:

```
class V01Controller extends Controller {

    public function initialize() {
        parent::initialize();
        $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
    }

    public function index() {
        $result = ['foo' => 'bar'];
        $this->set(compact('result'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['result']);
    }

    public function getUpdate() {
        $lastUpdated = $this->request->query('lastUpdated');
        // todo
        $result = ['foo' => 'bar'];
        $this->set(compact('result'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['result']);
    }

}
```

When the request with this `/api/v01.json`, it is well response as described in document.

But when I try to request with my old request `/api/v01/getUpdate.json?lastUpdated=1234567890` I've got this `Error: ApiController could not be found.`

Please help me how to custom the method work in CakePHP 3. I don't know if I miss / wrong configuration :'(

Answer (score 1):

The action `getUpdate` is not in the list of `index, add, edit, view, delete`, so you need to create a route for it or to instruct the `resources()` method to map your action as described in the manual:

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#mapping-additional-resource-routes

Comment: thank you the answer. but I have many methods in that controller, do i need to make all manual routes? if YES :'( because I have many versions of my API (around 7 versions in one project), do it have any easy way to do that? I mean one configuration for all or for one version.

Answer (score 1):

in routes.php

```php
Router::scope('/api', function ($routes) {
    $routes->extensions(['json', 'html']);
    $routes->resources('V01',array('map'=>
                                  array('getup' =>[
                                       'action' => 'getUpdate',
                                       'method' => 'GET', 
                                       'path' => 'getupdate']
                                      )
                              )
                         );
});
```

in case if webapp sending OPTIONS before POST

```php
Router::scope('/api', function ($routes) {
    $routes->extensions(['json', 'html']);
     $routes->resources('V01',array('map'=>
                                   array('getup-opt' =>[
                                       'action' => 'getUpdate',
                                       'method' => 'OPTIONS', 
                                       'path' => 'getupdate'
                                       ],
                                       'getup-post' =>[
                                       'action' => 'getUpdate',
                                       'method' => 'POST', 
                                       'path' => 'getupdate'
                                       ],
                                      )

                              )
                         );
});
```

Comment: Is it possible to define parameters? I'm trying to get `api/{resource}/{id}/validate` recognized but no luck so far